# Cocoapods and GGLContext error

Tags: xcode, swift, admob, cocoapods

I've been reading thru all the help and other posts.. but I am obviously missing something.  I am using Cocoapods for the Google APIs.  I have installed them on my mac, and I am using the workspace that it created for my app.  The following code is giving me an error:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class InformationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.bannerView.adUnitID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().adUnitIDForBannerTest
        self.bannerView.rootViewController = self
        self.bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())


    }
}
```

I receive an error in xcode that GGLContext is an unresolved identifier.

```
pod update has setup the following Pods.xconfig:
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleMobileAds/Frameworks"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GGLAdMob/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Google" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Google/Google" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds/Loading" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds/Loading/Formats" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds/Loading/Options" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds/Mediation" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds/Search" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleNetworkingUtilities" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities"
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(PODS_ROOT)/Google/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/Google/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries" "$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries"
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Google" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Google/Google" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds/Loading" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds/Loading/Formats" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds/Loading/Options" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds/Mediation" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds/Search" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleNetworkingUtilities" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"GGLAdMob" -l"GGLCore" -l"GSDK_Overload" -l"GTMSessionFetcher_core" -l"GTMSessionFetcher_full" -l"GTMStackTrace" -l"GTM_AddressBook" -l"GTM_DebugUtils" -l"GTM_GTMURLBuilder" -l"GTM_KVO" -l"GTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments" -l"GTM_NSScannerJSON" -l"GTM_NSStringHTML" -l"GTM_NSStringXML" -l"GTM_Regex" -l"GTM_RoundedRectPath" -l"GTM_StringEncoding" -l"GTM_SystemVersion" -l"GTM_UIFont+LineHeight" -l"GTM_core" -l"GTM_iPhone" -framework "AVFoundation" -framework "AddressBook" -framework "AudioToolbox" -framework "CoreGraphics" -framework "CoreMedia" -framework "CoreTelephony" -framework "EventKit" -framework "EventKitUI" -framework "GoogleMobileAds" -framework "MessageUI" -framework "StoreKit" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -weak_framework "AdSupport"
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

I am also have set my Header Search Path as follows:

[image: Header Search Path]

How can I clear this error and get my app to compile ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok closing this one.. I have went back to direct entry of my adUnitID and removed the dependency on GGLContext.  Everything compiles fine.